# NullPointerException with ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, arraylist, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I am using Eclipse, I have an activity using the default "RelativeLayout" layout. I included a spinner into the layout, here is the current xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="mahana.timestat.InputMenu" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/activitiesSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my .java, I find the spinner, create an arrayList, fill it manually, create an adapter and set it as the adapter for the spinner. Here is the code:

```
//find the spinner:
Spinner activitiesSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.activitiesSpinner);
//create an arrayList:
ArrayList<String> activities = new ArrayList<String>();
//clear it and insert two strings:
activities.clear();
activities.add("First");
activities.add("Second");
//create an adapter (I expect the error to be somewhere in here)
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.id.activitiesSpinner, activities);
//and finally set the adapter for the spinner
activitiesSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I use the `adapter.getCount()` method, it shows the right number (2).
When I comment the last line, where I set the adapter, it runs fine and shows an empty spinner on my device.
When I leave the last line in and run this, it crashes on a nullPointerException. Here is the trace:

```
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): Process: mahana.timestat, PID: 21432
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:392)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:193)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:504)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2373)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1964)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1160)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1342)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1047)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
10-02 19:50:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I tried looking this problem up, I mostly found that people accidentally left a null value somewhere in their arrayList, but that is definitely not my problem here as I fill it manually.
Any ideas on where the problem might be would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using default `simple_spinner_item` layout so which contain `TextView` with `text1` id instead of Spinner. so instead of passing `R.id.activitiesSpinner` as third parameter in ArrayAdapter constructor pass `android.R.id.text1` :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
                                android.R.id.text1, activities);
```

OR

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,activities);
```

Comment: Thank you, both versions you posted work. Now I just have to try and understand why. I'm new to both Java and Android development. Do I understand correctly that the third parameter expects NOT the actual spinner, but the **textView** which represents the line of text in the dropdown menu in a spinner?

Comment: @Mahana : yes in first version `TextView` is for dropdown rows in spinner